# Whether or not a "what" is needed after "than"

Tags: comparatives

Please compare these 2 sentences.

> 1, lf you are overqualified for a particular job, you have more experience or training than __ is needed. (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)
>
> 2, The magnification is usually at least thirty times greater than **what** is normally seen with the naked eye. (Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)

In the first sentence, there is a blank after "than", while, in a similar case, sentence 2, a "what" is put in that blank.

I want to make sure if, in both of the the sentences above, a **what** is optional.

Comment: I would point out that these sentences are wordy; they could be shortened in several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to slightly modify the sentences as:
1) lf you are overqualified for a particular job, you have more experience or training than needed. 
2) The magnification is usually at least thirty times what is normally seen with the naked eye. (greater than... is redundant)

At the same time, your sentences: 
1) lf you are overqualified for a particular job, you have more experience or training than what is needed. 
2) The magnification is usually at least thirty times greater than what is normally seen with the naked eye.

...are not grammatically wrong, but for the bits of refinements.